# "Raw" Packages of Oracle JDK for Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, java

Is there any public source of zipped JDKs for Linux (64bit) that can be downloaded and used more easily than the original installers or the PPA? Currently we create them ourselves manually, but that is always a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you want the Oracle JDK, you have to download it from Oracle and agree to their license.

However, I'm not sure which PPA you're referring to, but [this one](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) at least automates that process for you.  Once you install the oracle-java7-installer package, it will download and install the zip files for you each time the package is updated, in the same way as the flash-installer package.

Another option is to use the [oab-java](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6) script to automatically create the package .debs for you, and install them in a local apt repository.

Comment: @Elmar Weber - edited to provide some more options.

Comment: Thanks, the PPA as not an option since I do not want to have it installed, this is more for production and build environments where I have to mange a specific version or several in parallel. But I can use the scripts of course to create packages that fit our needs.

Comment: For this situation I host an apt repository for our LAN, with a higher pin value than the standard update sources.  So to fix on a particular version of some package, all I have to do is keep that version in the local apt repository.  That would work with either the PPA or oab-java packages that I mentioned above.